# JPA equivalent to Hibernate's @NaturalId

Tags: hibernate, jpa, naturalid

In Hibernate I can create a unique key using `@NaturalId` on several properties of the entity.

Is there a JPA equivalent annotation, something that is a part of `javax.persistence`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What I usually do is add a unique constraint on the columns, using `@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={column_1, ..., column_n}))`

Comment: And you also need to set nullable=false, as it is implied by Hibernate's NatuarlId

Comment: This will not replace an @Id column. Petr's answer is correct.

Comment: @Amalgovinus The question implied that the desired solution should create a unique key. It was not necessary to mimic the workings of the NaturalId annotation exactly. My answer clearly states that I add unique constraints to columns, I don't pretend I am replacing the NaturalId annotation.

Comment: @Amalgovinus I'm using `@NaturalId` as a "secondary" id, together with `@Id Integer id`. `@NaturalId` really like an unique constraints together with NOT NULL and I doubt, it can be used as primary id.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is not. You will have to use composite keys, so either [EmbeddedId](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EmbeddedId.html) or [IdClass](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/IdClass.html) depending what you prefer.