# EclipseLink what is the equivalent of the NaturalID concept from Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I would like to use EclipseLink as a persistence provider and if possible even use JPA annotations, only. I found the following question here on stackoverflow, which I think contains the wrong answer marked as "answered":

[JPA equivalent to Hibernate's @NaturalId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14254083/jpa-equivalent-to-hibernates-naturalid)

Why is it wrong? Because simply adding a unique constraint to a field/column is NOT what naturalID provides as the main benefit in the hibernate world. "@naturalID" provides very important Level 2 cache capabilities, which I would like to use in the future as well. See more details in the following stackoverflow answer:

[What is a natural identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910220/what-is-a-natural-identifier)

Any suggestions/ideas? From the documentation in EclipseLink I could see anything that looks similar... .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@cacheindex and it's array equivalent helps you achieve L2 hits even if querying by natural (business) keys and not just @id.